# Is the top hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^1$ a retract?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{S}^1$, centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Consider the top hemisphere $\mathbb{H} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{S}^1 \mid y \geq 0 \} $.

Is there a continuous retraction from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{H}$?

**Attempt**: Yes, because reflection across the x-axis is continuous?

Comment: That's correct, or to say it better, the map which is the identity on and above the $x$-axis, and the reflection on and below the $x$-axis, is continuous, namely $(x,y) \to (x,|y|)$.

Comment: Semicircle might be a better choice of word here though.

Comment: @LeeMosher - Ah I see now. The norm is continuous. So, $f(x,y) = (x, norm(y))$ is continuous since each component is. Thanks! +1

Comment: ..is continuous *and idempotent* (so is a retraction).

Comment: @drhab - Yes, we need $f = id$ when restricted to $\mathbb{S}^1$. Thanks!

Comment: If there were such a retraction, the two sets would be homotopy equivalent, thus they would have the same fundamental group. Do they?

Comment: @AlexM. - Restraction exists, but it is not a deformation retraction (i.e. homotopy equivalent). E.g. every space $X$ has a retract $g(X) = x \in X$ to a point. but they are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Ah, my bad, terminology misunderstanding. I find the question slightly ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexM. - Thanks a lot for pointing out possible problems! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally,  the map $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to (x_1,\dots,|x_n|)$ is a retraction of $S^{n-1}$ onto its upper half. As was noted in comments, this is not a deformation retraction; there isn't one since the hemisphere is contractible while the sphere is not.